# Encode-Decode issue php (CSV->MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to pull data in CSV format for a server, process and store in a MySQL database:

When I insert into my database, the text is "Atila%27s+Goonies" I want it to be "Atila's Goonies"

I have been reading through all the text encoding topics, but I think I'm missing a very simple function.

My requirement is to have this text and store in the database as a properly formatted (or encoded) string, so I can query later and display online. Database column is collated as "utf8_unicode_ci". I'm not sure if it's relevant because if I want to display on the browser, I cannot get to the correct format either. thanks.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code below:

```
if (($handle = fopen("alliances.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $row++;
        $alliance_id = $data[0];
        $alliance_name = $data[1];
        $alliance_points = $data[2];
        $alliance_villages = $data[3];
        $alliance_members = $data[4];
        $alliance_rank = $data[5];
        
        
         $sql_ia = "insert into alliances (alliance_id,alliance_name, alliance_villages,alliance_members,alliance_rank,timestamp) 
                                     values (:alliance_id,:alliance_name, :alliance_villages,:alliance_members,:alliance_rank,:timestamp)";
         $st_ia = $DBcon->prepare($sql_ia);
         $st_ia->bindParam(':alliance_rank', $alliance_rank,PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $st_ia->bindParam(':alliance_id', $alliance_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $st_ia->bindParam(':alliance_name',$alliance_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $st_ia->bindParam(':alliance_members',$alliance_members,PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $st_ia->bindParam(':alliance_villages',$alliance_villages,PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $st_ia->bindParam(':timestamp',$timestamp,PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $author_name = $ag_row[$agency];
        
         $st_ia->execute();       
     
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php

$encoded = 'Atila%27s+Goonies';
// Your string is URL encoded. Use urldecode() to decode.
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);

var_dump($decoded); // string(15) "Atila's Goonies"
```